# Any helper methods for stop/start on the Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: java, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using google cloud datastore from a Java app that will not be running in AppEngine.

I want to use the LocalDevelopmentDatastore in a manner where I can launch it in-memory for the scope of a test and then shut it down. (AppEngine has some nice helper classes for this).

I keep getting a LocalDevelopmentDatastoreException when issuing a LocalDevelopmentDatastore.start command.  The exception says "Unexpected option(s): datastore-pre --allow-remote-shutdown"

The code causing the issue is captured in the try-block below:

```
DatastoreOptions options = new DatastoreOptions.Builder().host("http://localhost:8080").dataset("datastore-pre").build();

LocalDevelopmentDatastore localRunner = LocalDevelopmentDatastoreFactory.get().create(options);

try {
    localRunner.start("/home/h____s/projects/gcd-v1beta2-rev1-2.1.1", "datastore-pre --testing");
} catch (LocalDevelopmentDatastoreException ex) {
    return null;
}

return localRunner;
```

Comment: There's a fix for this coming in the next version of Cloud Datastore. You can get updates by following [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/53) in the GitHub project.

Comment: I saw that ticket.  It was 6 months ago. are there nightlies i can pull?